# Amazon DynamoDB throttling

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've enabled auto-scaling for our dynamo-db table. It has a target utilization at 30% but it keeps throttling.

See this [example screenshot where throttling is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87OCN.png)

As you can see it's exactly scaling up as you want it too. But I don't understand why it's still throttling. Its almost always below the provisioned throughput.

Can anyone explain what's going wrong and why it's still throttling?

Thanks,
Hendrik

Comment: Could be because you are getting throttled at that partition due to non-uniform data access. It is hard to tell by just looking at the graph. Maybe [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions) could help isolate and determine the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to tell from the graph, and limited information.

Some thoughts:

1. AutoScaling can take 5 - 10 minutes to kick in. This is not fast enough if there is a sudden increase in usage. Perhaps you are seeing throttling in that 5 - 10 minute window before it scales up.

If you set CloudWatch Metrics to 1 min interval, you might see whats going on in a big more detail.

2. As mkobit mentioned, you might be hitting throughput on your Partition, depending on how your data is structured.

Your capacity units are evenly distributed between your partitions. So you may hit the capacity limit on your partition you have and which records you are trying to access, but not your table throughput.
This also depends on the amount of data you have stored, number of partitions etc.

HTH